# detect UITableViewCell id on UIImageView

Tags: iphone

I have a UITableView.
I place an UIImageView on each row UITableViewCell.
I used the codes below to detect the touch on the UIImageViews

```
-(void) touchBegan:(NSSet*) touches withEven:(UIEvent*)event
{
CGPoint pt=[[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];


}
```

It looks like I can only get the pt,
Is it possbile to detect which row's UIImageView is touched?

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible (UITableView has a method allowing to what row specific point belongs to):

```
-(void) touchBegan:(NSSet*) touches withEven:(UIEvent*)event
{
   CGPoint pt=[[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
   CGPoint pointInTable = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:yourTableView];
   NSIndexPath* path = [yourTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:pointInTable];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But it looks like only worked when I touch the part outside UITableView. Do I need to set any protocol between touch any UITableView?

Comment: sorry, can't see the problem...In what class are you tracking touches? And do you really need to use UIIMageView? May be you can use UIButton with background image - it will be easier to handle events on it

Answer (score 0):

In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you could set the imageview's tag property to the current row index.  Then just read the tag off the imageview to see which row it's in.