# buttontap on cell.image

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

well there is the

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

but this is for the `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;`

How can i catch a clickevent on the cell.Image?

Comment: Go throught the below SO post.
@Vladimir have given good answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394846/detect-uitableviewcell-id-on-uiimageview

Comment: Thank you, ill have a look at it!

Answer (score 0):

UIImage view does not decsend from UIControl that's why it does not have Touchepinside like target action method. So what I guess you can do is Create a UIButton object. Then set an image for it's normal state:

```
[imageButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.png"]
      forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Then set it's target action:

```
[imageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPushed:)
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And then :

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:imageButton];
```

I guess that'll do the job.